# Regular expression: cannot start with and exact number of digits

Tags: regex

I have to match a set of numbers that do not start with "3400" and must exactly be 13 digits.

So far this is what I've got:

```
^(?:(?!3400).)*$
```

this makes it match with a set of characters that does not start with "3400"; but how do I impose the restriction of 13 digits?

Comment: Are you looking for `^(?!3400)\d{13}$`? Or are you extracting them from larger text (then try using `\b(?!3400)\d{13}\b`)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your first suggestion is what I was looking for! thank you.
but if i want to make it match with a set that does not start with "3400" **AND** "3401", shouldn't this do the trick: `^(?!3400)\d{13}$|^(?!3401)\d{13}$`?

Comment: You may use `^(?!340[01])\d{13}$`. Or `^(?!3400|3401)\d{13}$` but it is much less efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `^(?:(?!3400).)*$` pattern matches a string consisting of any chars other than line break chars, 0+ occurrences, that does not contain `3400` substring.

What you seek is to match a string consisting of 13 digits only and does not start with some custom digit sequences.

Use

```
^(?!3400])\d{13}$
```

to match 13 digit string that does not start with `3400`.

You may further customize the pattern, e.g. to also avoid matching number strings starting with both `3400` and `3401` using

```
^(?!340[01])\d{13}$
       ^^^^
```

where `[01]`  is a character class matching either `0` or `1`. `^(?!3400|3401)\d{13}$` is also possible, but it is best practice that alternatives should not match at the same location (and here, they both match `340`), which impacts performance, especially with longer patterns and many more alternatives.